# Null values from 2nd query in a subquery join

Tags: postgresql, join, subquery

I have data regarding users, their create dates, and their login counts. I'm trying to get the Month/Year, the count of users created in said month/year, and the number of logins from those users in the same month/year, for the past 3 years. I'm joining our user table to our actions table for this.

I'd like to have a column output like this:

```
Year/Month  UsersCreated  Year/Month  UsersLogin
2018-01         25        2018-01         20
2018-02         45        2018-01         36
```

...and so on

The query I am using below is pulling the correct year/month and count for UsersCreated, but is pulling only nulls for the Year/Month UsersLogin count.

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(SELECT
to_char(u.created_at, 'yyyy-mm'),
count(u.id) as usercount
FROM user as u
LEFT JOIN actions as a on u.id = a.user_id
where a.action = 'account_created'
and u.type = 'AccountUser'
and u.name not like '%test%'
group by to_char(u.created_at, 'yyyy-mm')) as a
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT
to_char(a.created_at, 'yyyy-mm'),
count(distinct u.id) as usercount
FROM user as u
LEFT JOIN actions as a on u.id = a.user_id
where a.action = 'user_login'
and u.type = 'AccountUser'
and u.name not like '%test%'
GROUP BY to_char(a.created_at, 'yyyy-mm')) as b
ON a.usercount = b.usercount;
```

Both queries, if run on their own without the join, populate correct results, so I'm not sure if I'm just not joining the subqueries correctly or if there is an improper grouping somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to join on the result of `to_char()`, give that column an identical name on both subqueries and join on that name.